# Python set from file memory optimization

Tags: python, memory, membership, large-data

I am very new to python. In a python script I need to check if input string is present in the set 'titles'; which I load from newline separated strings in files 'titles'. It consumes huge memory. I chose to store in set because there is `if inputstring in titles:` later on.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     1    6.160 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     2                             def loadtitles():
     3  515.387 MiB  509.227 MiB     titles = open('titles').read().split()
     4  602.555 MiB   87.168 MiB     titles = set(titles)
```

**Q1. Is there any other object type more memory efficient to store this large data?**

One solution I can come up with is if I load file as string, it consumes exactly the same memory as filesize; which is 100% optimal consumption of memory.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     1    6.160 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     2                             def loadtitles():
     3  217.363 MiB  211.203 MiB     titles = open('titles').read()
```

then I can do `if inputstring+'\n' in titles:`

**Q2. Is there a faster alternative to this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- use a key/value store if you lookup lots of keys.
- iterate over the file line by line and check for keys' existence if there are only a few keys to lookup.

Comment: Using [dict](http://i.imgur.com/Ghf56HY.png) or shelve, it saves about 128 MiB memory. Any improvements you can suggest for that?

Comment: @Nexu, what memory threshold would satisfy you? You can't endlessly keep lowering memory footprint as you'll never reach satisfactory results.

Comment: dict will do for me (@ 500M memory). I was simply asking if that code could still be made more efficient somehow with any alternative dictionary-like objects.

Comment: @Nexu, you could presort the input file and create table with offsets for each starting char. You could use lru cache for dict object. You could use memcached/redis/sqlite3/postgres or any other db engine

Answer (score 1):

Iterating file (processing line by line) instead of reading full contents of file will reduce memory consumption. (combining with generator expression):

```
def loadtitles():
    with open('titles') as f:
        titles = {word for line in f for word in line.split()}
```

Comment: @Nexu, `titles = set(titles)` is not necessary. `title` is already `set` object. (`{ ... for .. in ... }` is set comprehension.)

Comment: Oh yes. [Screenshot2](http://i.imgur.com/bOmiyjc.png). Saves only 1 MiB though. (python 2.7.3)

Comment: Somehow, the one you [suggested](http://ideone.com/B7PfMe) was way too slow. I think I'll stick with string in string comparison for now.

Comment: @Nexu, Does `if inputstring in titles` multiple times or just once?

Comment: Twice. With slightly different strings checked. It executes on user input. How will that affect it?

Comment: @Nexu, string in string could yiled wrong result. For instance, `'or' in 'hello world'` yields `True`.

Comment: That is correct. Although 'titles' file contains values which are separated by newline and I am doing `inputstring+'\n' in titles`. So I guess that shouldn't be erronous.

Comment: @Nexu, If it run only once, you can [try this](http://ideone.com/r4wjy3). But as kroolik answered, it's better to use key/value pair storage if search performed multiple times.